# VBA SUMIF then Delete Duplicate Row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro (I know that a Pivot can also accomplish it; however, I need a macro).  I need a macro to Sumif the Values in Col D if it matches the Criteria in Col A.  Then I want to delete all the other values and only leave the sumif value.

For Example

```
Col A    ColD
AB       10
CD       5
FG       25
HI       100
AB       50
FG       0
OP       500
HI       80
OP       66
```

Then

```
Col A    ColD
AB       60
CD       5
FG       25
HI       180
OP       566
```

Currently I am using the following code but its not working

```
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Rng As Range
Set Sh = Worksheets(1)
Sh.Columns(5).Insert
LastRow = Sh.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
With Sh.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Offset(0, 4)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIF(R1C[-4]:RC[-4],RC[-4])>1,"""",SUMIF(R1C[-4]:R[" & LastRow & "]C[-4],RC[-4],R1C[-1]:R[" & LastRow & "]C[-1]))"
    .Value = .Value
End With
Sh.Columns(4).Delete
Sh.Rows(1).Insert
Set Rng = Sh.Range("D1:D" & LastRow + 1)
With Rng
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sumif formula is summing from the wrong column:
Your RC notation is equivalent to :

`=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)>1,"",SUMIF(A$1:A10,A1,D$1:D10))`

But you want:
`=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)>1,"",SUMIF(A$1:A10,A1,b$1:b10))`

Correct it with this:

`.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIF(R1C[-4]:RC[-4],RC[-4])>1,"""",SUMIF(R1C[-4]:R[" & LastRow & "]C[-4],RC[-4],R1C[-3]:R[" & LastRow & "]C[-3]))"`

Comment: This was pretty easy to debug, by the way.  I put my cursor on the .value=.value line and hit F9 to force a pause there.  I hit f5 to run up to that point, then examined the formula that had been put into the temporary summation column.

Comment: Also after i set the worksheet to activesheet it worked